Prove that the AP (km + 1), k belongs to N contains infinite primes for any fixed integer m.
So I found this statement given as a property in a pdf but on research I could not find a proof for it. I tried proving it myself and I could prove it for certain values of m (like 2) but how can I prove that this holds for ANY value of m? I want to know how exactly I am supposed to frame the induction step if any or any other generalized solution that exists.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Look at Dirichlet’s Theorem on Arithmetic Progressions (it is not easy!)
